# I'm executing the Code : nlp.vocab['Hun'].vector and obtain a ValueError : [E010] Word vectors set to length 0

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

All the code I am executing is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import spacy
from spacy.vocab import Vocab
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(open("pg345.txt").read())
tokens = list(set([w.text for w in doc if w.is_alpha]))*

nlp.vocab['Hun'].vector
```

but when I execute the last line I obtain:

ValueError: [E010] Word vectors set to length 0. This may be because you don't have a model installed or loaded, or because your model doesn't include word vectors

Python version: 3.7.4

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using `nlp('cheese').vector` **instead of** `nlp.vocab['cheese'].vector`

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. This is by reading the article "Understanding word vectors" by Allison Parrish in [link]https://gist.github.com/aparrish/2f562e3737544cf29aaf1af30362f469 . I could solve the problem by doing what it is mentioned in this comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The small model (`en` is a shortcut for `en_core_web_sm`) doesn't include vectors. Download `en_core_web_md` or `en_core_web_lg` instead to have vectors.